# How to test variables that exist inside module

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

How can I test something like this:

```
const map = new Map<string, string>();

export function handleLogic() {
  // some code 
  if (!map.has(id)) {
    // do some stuff
  } else {
    // do some stuff
  }
}
```

I want to conditionally test the if statement. I know I can export the map const, but I don't think I should expose the map const.

Is there a way to add the id to the map, so I can test the else without exporting the map const?

Hope you can give me some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make 2 tests :

- The first instantiates a `new Map()`, apply it `//some code` without setting id, then call `handleLogic()`
- The second one instantiates a `new Map()`, apply it `//some code` and set the id to your Map with `yourMap.set('id', '123')`, then call `handleLogic()`

Then you would have your if statement covered.

**Update 1 :**

As requested, here's how I would implement it. I assume you don't want to pass parameter to your `handleLogic()` function, so you will have to play with your function **`context`**. For example :

```js
// main.js
const map = new Map();

export function handleLogic() {
  this.map.set('john', 'doe')  // Here we use current context, this.map === map
  if (!this.map.has('id')) return false
  return true
}
```

Your test file could look like this :

```js
// main.test.js
import { handleLogic } from './main'

test('it returns false without id', () => {
  const map = new Map()
  map.set('foo', 'bar')
  expect(handleLogicHandler(map)).toBe(false)
})

test('it returns true with id', () => {
  const map = new Map()
  map.set('foo', 'bar')
  map.set('id', '123')
  expect(handleLogicHandler(map)).toBe(true)
})

function handleLogicHandler(map) {
  this.map = map   // Here we define our own testing context
  return handleLogic.apply(this)  // and apply it to the function
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to jest. I don't exactly understand where I should instanciate a new map(). If you have some time, could you post an example?

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one last question. Lets say I have something like this: property.on("event", () => handleLogig()). Is it still possible? I use jest.spyOn(property, "on").mock.calls[0][1]() to trigger the arrow function, but I don't know how to pass an extra property "map" like in your example.

Comment: You could use the same logic as in the `handleLogicHandler(map)` :
`property.on("event", (map = undefined) => {
       this.map = map
       handleLogic().apply(this)
   })`

And in your call test :
`const map = new Map()
  map.set('id', '123')
  jest.spyOn(property, "on").mock.calls[0][1](map)
`
Tell me if this works as intended ?

A simpler way would be to add a parameter to your `handleLogic(map)` function tho :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try this tomorrow. Will let you know!